# building PyMC3 model incorporating different measurements

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to incorporate different types and replicates of measurements into one model in PyMC3.

Consider the following model: P(t)=P0*exp(-k*B*t) where P(t), P0, and B are concentrations. k is a rate. We measure P(t) at different times and B once, all through counting of particles. k is the parameter of interest we are trying to infer.

My question has two parts:
(1) How to incorporate measurements on P(t) and B into one model?
(2) How to use a variable number of replicate experiments to inform on the value of k?

I think I can answer part (1), but am unsure about whether it is right or done in the right flavour. I failed to generalise the code to include a variable number of replicates.

For one experiment (one replicate):

```
ts=np.asarray([time0,time1,...])
counts=np.asarray([countforB,countforPattime0,countforPattime1,...])
basic_model = pm.Model()
with basic_model:
    k=pm.Uniform('k',0,20)
    B=pm.Uniform('B',0,1000)
    P=pm.Uniform('P',0,1000)
    exprate=pm.Deterministic('exprate',k*B)
    modelmu=pm.math.concatenate(B*(np.asarray([1.0]),P*pm.math.exp(-exprate*ts)))
    Y_obs=pm.Poisson('Y_obs',mu=modelmu,observed=counts))
```

I tried to include different replicates along the lines of the above, but to no avail:

```
...
    k=pm.Uniform('k',0,20) # same within replicates
    B=pm.Uniform('B',0,1000,shape=numrepl) # can vary between expts.
    P=pm.Uniform('P',0,1000,shape=numrepl) # can vary between expts.
    exprate=???
    modelmu=???
```

Comment: Edited to remove typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Multiple Observables

PyMC3 supports multiple observables, that is, you can add multiple `RandomVariable` objects to the graph with the `observed` argument set.

#### Single Trial

In your first case, this would lend some clarity to the model:

```
counts=[countforPattime0, countforPattime1, ...]

with pm.Model() as single_trial:
    # priors
    k = pm.Uniform('k', 0, 20)
    B = pm.Uniform('B', 0, 1000)
    P = pm.Uniform('P', 0, 1000)

    # transformed RVs
    rate = pm.Deterministic('exprate', k*B)
    mu = P*pm.math.exp(-rate*ts)

    # observations
    B_obs = pm.Poisson('B_obs', mu=B, observed=countforB)
    Y_obs = pm.Poisson('Y_obs', mu=mu, observed=counts)
```

#### Multiple Trials

With this additional flexibility, hopefully it makes the transition to multiple trials more obvious.  It should go something like:

```
B_cts = np.array(...) # shape (N, 1)
Y_cts = np.array(...) # shape (N, M)
ts = np.array(...)    # shape (1, M)

with pm.Model() as multi_trial:
    # priors
    k = pm.Uniform('k', 0, 20)
    B = pm.Uniform('B', 0, 1000, shape=B_cts.shape)
    P = pm.Uniform('P', 0, 1000, shape=B_cts.shape)

    # transformed RVs
    rate = pm.Deterministic('exprate', k*B)
    mu = P*pm.math.exp(-rate*ts)

    # observations
    B_obs = pm.Poisson('B_obs', mu=B, observed=B_cts)
    Y_obs = pm.Poisson('Y_obs', mu=mu, observed=Y_cts)
```

There might be some extra syntax stuff to get the matrices multiplying correctly, but this at least includes the correct shapes.

---

### Priors

Once you get that setup working, it would be in your interest to reconsider the priors. I suspect you have more information about the typical values for those than is currently included, especially since this seems like a chemical or physical model.

For instance, right now the model says,

> We believe the true value of `B` remains fixed for the duration of a trial, but across trials is *a completely arbitrary value between 0 and 1000*, and measuring it repeatedly within a trial would be Poisson distributed.

Typically, one should avoid truncations unless they are excluding meaningless values. Hence, a lower bound of 0 is fine, but the upper bounds are arbitrary.  I'd recommend having a look at [the Stan Wiki on choosing priors](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations).

Comment: Thanks, @merv. This is exactly what I was looking for. The comments on my priors is also highly appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, is it correct to say that use of pm.Deterministic is only necessary to keep track of transformed RVs? Are there other reasons why to do so?

Comment: @wpm yes, that's the primary use AFAIK. I've never ran into another use case for them.